# Python Pandas - Best way to add additional rows to Indexed data frames and manipulating them

Tags: python, pandas

New to Python and Pandas

I'm trying to figure out the best way to take my data frame and do some operations on each row by creating additional rows. This is what I have:

```py
        X     Y
Data    50    100
Data2   30     70
```

where my `Data` is indexed. What I'm trying to do is apply operations on each `X` and `Y` and run in through a 360 degree sweep so that each "Angle" would sweep so kinda like this:

```py
         X    Y    Angle
Data     50   100    0
         55   110    1
         22   40     2

Data 2    30   70    0
          33    15   1
```

Any ideas on how to do this? Basically I will be using the angle and the `X` and `Y` values and applying Cosine or Sin Functions to them. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It would help to share what algorithm or math you are trying to apply to get at the desired output, and code for what you've tried so far, and how the output was different than what you need

Answer (score 0):

Something along those lines should do the trick for you:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({"X": [50,30], "Y": [100,70]}, index=["Data", "Data2"])

def rotate_matrix(alpha):
    alpha=np.pi/180*alpha#so we get grad
    return np.array([[np.cos(alpha), -np.sin(alpha)], [np.sin(alpha), np.cos(alpha)]])
#code to rotate by 90 Grads only Data2, and add it with Data2 index
df2=df.loc["Data2", ["X", "Y"]].to_frame().T.apply(lambda l: pd.Series({id: el[0] for el, id in zip(np.dot(rotate_matrix(90), [[l["X"]], [l["Y"]]]), list("XY"))}), axis=1)
df=pd.concat([df, df2], axis=0, sort=True, ignore_index=False)
```

Output:

```py
          X      Y
Data   50.0  100.0
Data2  30.0   70.0
Data2 -70.0   30.0
```

Some additional house keeping:

```py
df["Angle"]=df.groupby(df.index).cumcount()
```

Output:

```py
          X      Y  Angle
Data   50.0  100.0      0
Data2  30.0   70.0      0
Data2 -70.0   30.0      1
```